# Custom datepicker with few years to select

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker, date-range

I have searched in google and hunted in stackoverflow.com for a particular solution. The problem is that, **I want to create a custom date picker**. The date picker dialog will open up on click of a button with a custom tile bar and maybe a custom background. **The most important customization will be the years showing up in the picker**.  **What I want to do is, I will allow the users to select a date which is minimum 18 years old from today and it can go up to a maximum of 50 years**. I have seen solutions to this problem which suggests to use `view.updateDate` on the datepicker to reset the datepicker inside the date range if the user tries to select anything out of the range. But, **I do not want to even show the years which are not in the range**. I only want the users to see the valid years from which he can select. The rest of the years should not even show up.

How can I customize the datepicker to give me the desired output?

Comment: What about `setMinDate(long minDate)` and `setMaxDate(long maxDate)` of datepickerdialog?

Comment: @PankajKumar how do you want me to go about it? I want to open the dialog onclick of a button!

Answer (score 1):

Thhis one will helpfull to you.

```
     DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                datePickerListener, year, month, day);


        long maxDate;
        Date newDate = c.getTime();
        dp.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate.getTime());
        dp.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate);
```

Comment: I want to open the date picker on click of a button, where should I put this code? What should be done in the onclick listener?